# Materialized View - Oracle

Tags: oracle, materialized-view

I have materialized view for which i want to alter its refresh time:

```
REFRESH FORCE START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE +1 DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
```

I want to know few things in this.

1. What does `NEXT SYSDATE +1` depict?
2. How am I going to change it (e.g after every 6 hours)?
3. What is `DISABLE QUERY REWRITE`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NEXT SYSDATE +1` means the materialized view will be automatically refreshed every day at the same time when the view is created.

In order to refresh the materialized view every 6 hours use `NEXT SYSDATE +6/24`

`DISABLE QUERY REWRITE` indicates that the materialized view is not eligible to be used by the query optimizer to [rewrite sql queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10736/qr.htm) on the base tables.

Comment: `SYSDATE + 1` tells the materialized view to start refreshing 24 hours after it finishes refreshing the last time.  If it takes 5 minutes to refresh, that means that the next refresh will be 5 minutes later the next day and the refresh time will slowly drift by 5 minutes a day.  This tends to catch folks out when they find that the materialized view that was set to refresh at 3am a couple months ago is now refreshing at 9am right when users are pounding the system.

Comment: Thats something interesting to know. Thanks.

Comment: just to add you can get round this drift [using `trunc`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF54190)

Comment: Here is an example for six hours: `create materialized view m1 refresh complete next trunc(sysdate) + ((trunc(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')/6)*6)+6)/24 as (select f1 from t1);`

Answer (score 2):

To support Raihan's correct answer<sup>+1</sup>, here are some excerpts from the [11.2 SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_2002.htm#SQLRF00808).

> **START WITH Clause**
>   Specify START WITH date to indicate a date for the first automatic
>   refresh time.
>
> **NEXT Clause**
>   Specify NEXT to indicate a date expression for calculating the
>   interval between automatic refreshes.
>
> **QUERY REWRITE Clause**
>   Specify DISABLE if you do not want the materialized view to be
>   eligible for use by query rewrite.